# Django Build URLs from template with integer param, the primary key

Tags: python, django

I have this link in a template:

```
<a href="{% url show_item item.id %}">Item 1</a>
```

and this url in the urls.py

```
url(r'item/(?P<id>)/$', show_item, name="page_item")
```

however, this error occurs:

```
Reverse for 'show_item' with arguments '(63L,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

I looked at this question:

[how to get python to not append L to longs or ignore in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404142/how-to-get-python-to-not-append-l-to-longs-or-ignore-in-django-template?rq=1)

but it did not help.

Is there another way to use the primary key, which is an integer, in constructing URLs in templates?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The URL name doesn't match.  Change the template to be:

```
<a href="{% url page_item item.id %}">Item 1</a>
```

Comment: accepting this as an answer, although also take note that there should be a \d on the captured param

Comment: As of Django 1.8, there should be quotes around url name: `<a href="{% url 'page_item' item.id %}">Item 1</a`

Answer (score 1):

It should be `page_item` not `show_item` in template.