# Getting a TemplateSyntaxError in my Django app

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I tried creating a delete button and basically what it should do is "delete an object when clicked" given its id but my app keeps giving a `TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: '{{doc.id}}' from '{{doc.id}}'`. Here's the code for  said functionality in my View, Template and Urls.py files respectively

## Views.py

```
def delete_feed(request, pk):
    query = Feed.objects.get(id=pk)
    query.delete()
    return HttpResponse("Deleted!")
```

## Template

```
<a href="{% url 'delete_feed' pk={{doc.id}} %}"><button type="button"    class="btn btn-danger">Delete Item</button></a>
```

## urls.py

```
url(r'^delete_feed/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', delete_feed, name='delete_feed'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like that

```
<a href="{% url 'delete_feed' pk=doc.id %}"><button type="button"    class="btn btn-danger">Delete Item</button></a>
```

we can cann't use within exprssion tag string interploation

if you want know more the document https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: what is stack trace ??

Comment: Thanks, This ultimately worked after i got rid of some other kinks in my javascript

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149288/django-build-urls-from-template-with-integer-param-the-primary-key).
You should double check how you pass the pk argument.

You can try to change

`<a href="{% url 'delete_feed' pk={{doc.id}} %}"...`

to

```
<a href="{% url 'delete_feed doc.id' %}"...
```

Comment: Not working. None of the answers in the "duplicate" works either

Comment: Could you please provide more info from the stack trace?
Also it would be great if you can provide how exactly is that line of code in your template.