# Expressing large numbers in Django Template

Tags: python, django

I have a certain large float number 1.4088564e+12 and I have a calendar app that accepts events in milliseconds. That form of the float is obviously no good to me, I need to express it in its true form. Is there a way to do that?

The way I express it is simply

```
{{ class.attribute }}
```

The float is of course stored in a FloatField.

Comment: What you most lkely have is a UNIX timestamp. Convert it to datetime in your view to be displayed in the template. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format numbers in django templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346467/format-numbers-in-django-templates)

Comment: If you don't want to do any math with those numbers, I think you should use a `CharField` instead of a `FloatField` or an `IntegerField`.