# Format integer thousands separator throughout the document

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

After months of web-development, I find myself completely helpless trying to find a good solution for a simple problem of formatting all the numbers throughout the DOM as I wish. Specifically, I have a js function **my_int_formatter**(), that I want to apply to all integers after the doc has been loaded. Best descriped by example - I want to do something like

```
<td>my_int_formatter({{django_variable}})</td>
```

I know the code above won't work, because I have to include 'script' tag, but first, I don't like the messy code, and second, javascript won't recognize python variable

I tried the following way:

HTML

```
<td class = 'my_integer'>{{django_variable}}</td>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // ....
   content = $('.my_integer').html();
   $('.my_integer').html(my_int_formatter(content));
```

...but as expected, I got wrong results because the js code applied the same html() content of the first .my_integer element in the DOM chain to all the others. Any ideas how to do this the short and correct way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use builtin `django.contrib.humanize` application: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/humanize/

You can format integers using some predefined filters, for example `intcomma`:

```
4500 becomes 4,500.
45000 becomes 45,000.
450000 becomes 450,000.
4500000 becomes 4,500,000.
```

Usage in your case would be like

```
{% load humanize %}
<td>{{django_variable|intcomma}}</td>
```

Also don't forget to include the app in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/346467/3606603) question might be useful

If you want to apply filter to all variables of some kind, I suggest you to use [Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) to fiddle with response before rendering.

Comment: Fantastic ! I underestimated Django again and looked for solution client-side, that's why the question you mentioned escaped my notice ))

Comment: Is there any way to tell Django to apply this format to ALL integers, unless explicitly stated otherwise ?

Comment: @Edgar Navasardyan I suggest to use middleware. See update in answer for doc link

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your problem isn't with the formatting but actualy applying the formatting to each of your dom elements.

Try using jquerys .each() function and using $(this).html() to actualy grab the content.

```
$('.my_integer').each(function(){
    content = $(this).html();
  $(this).html(content+"formatted");
});
```

here's a quick fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/57rdq2a0/2/

Comment: Starbug, I've ticked valentjedi's answer as solution because with his approach you don't have to loop through the entire DOM. I wonder, how expensive it is to loop this way, if you have large-scale site

Comment: Yeah, I noticed his reply after. A lot better to do the manipulation server side (I've nerer realy touched Django so couldn't help there). Jquery's each() can be heavy on a large scale site which is why it's always better to search fo ID's rather than classes in JS. Good luck ^^