# How to force dot on thousands separator?

Tags: python, format, locale, number-formatting, digit-separator

I already saw a lot of question teaching how easy is to do it with `comma` as thousands separator:

```
>>> format(1123000,',d')
'1,123,000'
```

But if I try to use a `dot`, it goes nuts:

```
>>> format(1123000,'.d')
ValueError: Format specifier missing precision
```

Is there a simple Python built-in **locale independent** way to make it output `'1.123.000'` instead of `'1,123,000'`?

I already found this answer on [Add 'decimal-mark' thousands separators to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38199025/4934640)
 but it manually do it. Can it be simpler as `format(1123000,'.d')` and **locale independent**? Or Python does not provide it built-in?

> [@Eugene Yarmash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244297) Using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) can give you some more flexibility:
>
> ```
> >>> from itertools import zip_longest
> >>> num = "1000000"
> >>> sep = "."
> >>> places = 3
> >>> args = [iter(num[::-1])] * places
> >>> sep.join("".join(x) for x in zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=""))[::-1]
> '1.000.000'
> ```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are only dealing with integers, you can use:

```
x = 123456789
'{:,}'.format(x).replace(',','.')
# returns
'123.456.789'
```

Comment: realyyyy??????? I solved my problem using django's humanize (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346467/format-numbers-in-django-templates), but this solution  sounds really strange...

Answer (score 2):

and if you want to add some decimals (e.g.: 2), you can just chain a few replace operations:

```
x = 123456789.123456789
'{:,.2f}'.format(x).replace(',','*').replace('.', ',').replace('*','.')
>>> '123.456.789,12'
```