# Humanize not working for floats in template

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django APP that has `LANGUAGE_CODE` set to `es` for Spanish.

I'm trying to format how the numbers are rendered in the templates. Right now they're rendered like:**`S/ 18,00` when `S/ 18.00` is needed**.

I've search and found this other related question:

[Format numbers in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346467/format-numbers-in-django-templates)

But after applying Humanize, I'm ***not*** getting the desired result:

***template.html***:

```
{% load humanize %}

<p>El total de su pedido es: S/ {{ total|intcomma }}</p> #renders S/ 18,00
```

***settings.py***:

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'shop',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
]
```

I've also tried these other solutions:

1) `<p>El total de su pedido es: S/ {{ total|floatformat:'2' }}</p>`

Doesn't work, renders: `S/ 18,00` when `S/ 18.00` is needed.

2) `<p>El total de su pedido es: S/ {{ total|stringformat:"f" }}</p>`

Works but uses more than 2 decimals: `S/ 18.00000000` when `S/ 18.00` is needed.

3) `<p>El total de su pedido es: S/ {{ total|stringformat:"2f" }}</p>`

This does not work, also returns: `S/ 18.00000000` when `S/ 18.00` is needed.

**models.py:**

```
class Order(models.Model):

    token = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

**views.py**

```
def thanks_deposit_payment(request):
    order_number = Order.objects.latest('id').id

    total = Order.objects.latest('id').total

    response = render(request, 'thanks_deposit_payment.html', dict(order_number=order_number, total=total))
    return response
```

Other language settings that may help:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try `{{ total|floatformat:2|intcomma }}`?

Comment: Also, give this a shot: `{% load l10n %}

{% localize on %}
    {{ total }}
{% endlocalize %}`

Comment: I've tested right now, and getting same result: `S/ 18,00`

Comment: Or: `{% load l10n %}

{{ value|localize }}`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_L10N OR https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#decimal-separator

Answer (score 0):

I had just to turn off these 2 variables in my `settings.py` file:

```
USE_I18N = False #Before True

USE_L10N = False #Before True
```

And in template I could just use:

```
{{ total }}
```

Thanks to Kendoka's comment for pointing me in the right direction.