# JS function only pick on first element in Django loop

Tags: javascript, django

My template code is as follows

```
{% for content in contentlist %}
  <div class="card card-margin-top">
      <div class="card-body">
           <div class="card-head">
              <p class="card-title">PRICE&nbsp;&#8208;&nbsp;
                        <span id="price">{{content.price}}</span>
              </p>
           </div>
      </div
  </div>           
{% endfor %}
```

and I want to convert my price value into a comma-separated value using the js function.
JS function is as follows

```
window.onload=function(){
  var price = document.getElementById("reservedPrice").innerText
  x = updateTextInput(price)
  document.getElementById("reservedPrice").innerText = x
}

function updateTextInput(val) {
  x = val.toString();
  var lastThree = x.substring(x.length-3);
  var otherNumbers = x.substring(0,x.length-3);
  if(otherNumbers != '')
      lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
  var res = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;
  return res
}
```

but in result looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogC5V.png). JS executing only on first entry. I want all prices to be comma-separated.

Comment: I guess you are trying to do comma separation for number values, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/347560/8601641) might help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggetion but I want to use comma separated values according to indian currency like 2,00,00,000 not 200,000,000

Comment: @AkshaySanas The problem is you set the id of an element in a loop. An elements id should be unique, when you write any code to change the element with an id only the first one would be selected. You want to use a class instead.

Comment: There is third party package similar to intcomma filter for Indian format see [this](https://github.com/narenchoudhary/django-indian-numbers).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I tried with class as well..can you tell me how can I use it please?

Comment: Thanks @k33da_the_bug the link works and working as expected..you saved my time